# How to remove every element from a list if the list is not empty using Java 8 lambda/streams using my service

Tags: java, list, lambda, service, java-stream

Hello I wanna update this legacy code using java 8.

```
if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listOfObjects){
 for(Object o : listOfObjects){
     objectService.delete(o);
  }
 }
```

I am fairly new to java 8 and lambda expressions and I would like to use it and reshape my code as much as possible. Not because it is always important but because I want to get used to it to be able to learn it easier.

Comment: Above code can be converted `listOfObjects.forEach(objectService::delete)`, but this does not match what you are saying in your question.

Comment: `if (listOfObjects != null) listOfObjects.forEach(objectService::delete);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your question is asking about removing elements from the list if it's not empty you can simply use `list.clear()` to clear it. Regarding to your legacy code refactoring to use Java8 features;

```
if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listOfObjects)) {
  for(Object o : listOfObjects){
    objectService.delete(o);
  }
}
```

Can be converted to use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) like below:

```
listOfObjects.forEach(objectService::delete)
```

This is a better place to use `method references` if you have a method which takes in only an `Object` parameter.